# Do Sullivan's and Wilkerson's algebraic group structures on rational homotopy automorphisms coincide?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, rational-homotopy-theory

For a 1-connected space $X$ with the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex, the homotopy automorphisms $\pi_0\,\mathrm{hAut}(X)$ are known to have the structure of an arithmetic group up to finite kernel. In fact, there are at least two such constructions in the literature:

- Sullivan's in Theorem 10.3 of [Infinitesimal computations in topology](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1977__47__269_0/).
- Wilkerson's in Theorem B of [Applications of minimal simplicial groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093837690001X).

In both cases the arithmetic group structure is obtained from the inclusion (up to finite kernel) of $\pi_0\,\mathrm{hAut}(X)$ into the homotopy automorphisms $\pi_0\,\mathrm{hAut}(X_\mathbb{Q})$ of the rationalisation $X_\mathbb{Q}$. Both references construct an $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic group structure on $\pi_0\,\mathrm{hAut}(X_\mathbb{Q})$, but since their constructions proceed along different lines it is not clear these coincide.

> Are Sullivan's and Wilkerson's algebraic group structures on $\pi_0\,\mathrm{hAut}(X_\mathbb{Q})$ the same?